# How to get Canvas DataURL on img.onload event when I click on submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to save the canvas as image on the server, I have a button to submit. When I click on save button I called a function that get the canvas dataURL on `img.onload` event. The problem is `img.onload` is fired after submitting the form, so I can't get dataURL value until it gets back from server.

Here's my code :

```
 <input onclick="savepoint('same');" id="btnsave" type="submit" value="Save Eyes Coordinate" />
```

```
function savepoint(btn) {

    SavePreviewImg();
}

function SavePreviewImg() {
    //Other code here to get the image src and other stuff..

    // here the excution of the function doesn't go into onload event it skip it
    // and after the click event finished it comes to onload event
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        // here i draw the first image
        ctx.drawImage(img, 480, 320);//210,10

        // here i draw the second image and put it on the first
        //image 
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(mx, my);
        ctx.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);
        ctx.drawImage(imge2, -(width / 2), -(height / 2), width, height);

        ctx.restore();

        //get img data url
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");//.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, and submit the form in `img.onload` event handler.

Comment: @Passerby, Thanks buddy, I found another solution. really appreciate your help.

Comment: This old question was solved without a solution being given, so I think we can close this as "typo/unreproduciple" for now.